# Dynamic namespace module pattern

Tags: javascript, dynamic, namespaces

Does anyone know what the pattern is for being able to create a module pattern but with being able to set the name space that the module lives under dynamically.

So instead of what is below:-

```
var MODULE = (function () { 
  var my = {}, 
      privateVariable = 1; 

  function privateMethod() { 
      // ... 
  } 

  my.moduleProperty = 1; 
  my.moduleMethod = function () { 
      // ... 
  }; 

  return my; 
}());
```

MODULE could be set to anything you like, I remember seeing it done i a screencast but can't remember where...

Basically i'd like to create a library that could be assigned to any namespace the implementer likes.

Comment: use a function rather then self executing functions? and require the user to call `var MODULE = lib();`

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'd just be able to add a method that lets you set it, and nullify `MODULE`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yrsdR/

```
my.namespace = function( ns ) {
    window[ns] = my;
    window.MODULE = null;
}
```

then:

```
window.MODULE.namespace( "myNamespace" );

window.MODULE; // null
window.myNamespace // object
```

or you could have it return the module to whatever variable you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/yrsdR/1/

```
my.namespace = function() {
    window.MODULE = null;
    return my;
}
```

```
window.myNamespace = MODULE.namespace();

window.MODULE; // null
window.myNamespace // object
```

Comment: but then your passing in a string. Ew.

Comment: @Raynos: Yeah, I just updated so that it returns the module instead. Probably a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Funny to come across this now, I just set up a new code base this way. This is how I approached it (it depends on 1 extra global variable however):

```
// ability to rename namespace easily
var AXS_NS = 'App';

window[AXS_NS] = (function (app, $, Modernizr) {

    app.config = {
        debug: false
    };

    app.init = function() {
        console.log('init');
    };

    return app;

})(window[AXS_NS] || {}, jQuery, Modernizr);
```

Then you could do:

```
jQuery(function($){
    App.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long ways after the original question.  And I'm not sure of the relevance of having a dynamically named javascript object.  But the following pattern does this is a reasonable way by allowing you to set up the object namespace name in the script element of your html page.

Something like

```
<script src="js/myscript.js" namespaceName="myObject"><script>
```

Which allows you to then call `myObject.hello()` in your javascript.

Example javascript that uses this solution.

```
/**
 * Dynamic mechanism for setting a javascript namespace.
 * 
 * This works by adding the namespaceName as an attribute to the script
 * element on your page.  Something like
 *
 *  **<script src="js/myscript.js" namespaceName="myObject"><script>**
 *
 * When the script has loaded it will have created a new javascript object
 * with the nemespace name "myObject".
 *
 * You can now use myObject.hello() which returns "ns.hello() called"<br/>
 * 
 * This works on later versions of chrome, firefox and ie.
 */
(function (ns) {
    ns.hello = function () {
        return "ns.hello() called";
    }
} (window[document.getElementsByTagName('script')[document.getElementsByTagName('script').length-1].attributes['namespaceName'].value]=
        window[document.getElementsByTagName('script')[document.getElementsByTagName('script').length-1].attributes['namespaceName'].value] || {}));
```

The 
    window[document.getElementsByTagName('script')
    [document.getElementsByTagName('script').length-1]
    .attributes['namespaceName'].value]
Is used to pull the attribute **namespaceName** value from the script load